# Gerar linhas de uma tabela com cores diferentes com laço de repetição

Tags: php, html, css

Como gerar linhas de uma tabela com cores diferentes? A cada vez que o laço for executado gerar uma linha com uma cor pré determinada?

**Ex.:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
foreach ($data as $key) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $key['value1'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $key['value2'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $key['value3'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $key['value4'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caso precise apenas disto, realmente não é necessário bibliotecas de terceiros, você pode utilizar CSS básico mesmo.

Primeiro você deve entender como os [*selectors*](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) do CSS funcionam.

Para a sua necessidade precisamos que cada linha da tabela seja de uma cor, então vou assumir que as linhas pares sejam padrão, fundo branco, e as impares terão seu *background* alterado.

Para isto, iremos usar o *selector* [nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) que aceita números, as literais *odd*(ímpar) e *even*(par) e também expressões no padrão *`an + b`*, sendo *`a`* o ciclo de repetição, *`b`* um *offset* e *`n`* um contador indexado de **`0`**.

Por exemplo a expressão *`2n + 1`* iria considerar os ímpares também, ou seja *`2 x 0 + 1 = 1`*, *`2 x 1 + 1 = 3`*, etc.

Usando esta tabela como exemplo:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Modelo</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Fiat</td>
            <td>Punto</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Volkswagen</td>
            <td>Fusca</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Ford</td>
            <td>Fiesta</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

No nosso CSS usaremos isto:

```css
tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Isto faz com que cada linha (`<tr>`) ímpar tenha sua cor alterada para amarelo, mas apenas as do corpo da tabela, ou seja, que estão em `<tbody>`.

Veja um exemplo completo, com um pouco mais de CSS:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody > tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Marca</th>
      <th>Modelo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fiat</td>
      <td>Punto</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Volkswagen</td>
      <td>Fusca</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Ford</td>
      <td>Fiesta</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Neste exemplo continuamos colocando o fundo amarelo para linhas impares do corpo da tabela, mas incluímos também uma borda sólida e simples.

Comment: perfeito! Ainda não tinha lido nada a respeito sobre os selectors. Com certeza vou estudar a respeito. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode executar isso usando o bootstrap, ele tem uma classe específica para tabelas zebradas.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<table class="table table-striped">
 <tr>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>Telefone</th>
  <th>Email</th>
 </tr>

 
 <tr>
  <td>Joao</td>
  <td>(11) 1111-1111</td>
  <td>joao@localhost</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>Maria</td>
  <td>(11) 1111-1111</td>
  <td>Maria@localhost</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>Jose</td>
  <td>(11) 1111-1111</td>
  <td>jose@localhost</td>
 </tr>
 
</table>
```

Comment: estou tentando não utilizar frameworks, pois é um projeto pra fins de aprendizado, quero entender como cada coisa funciona. Mas essa dica foi uma mão na roda! Vou estudar essa classe específica do Bootstrap e ver como funciona, pra tentar reproduzir. Obrigado pela ajuda!